# Can Kate automatically convert spaces/tabs?

Tags: kate

I got some files have mixed indentation, is there any way I can automatically convert the indentation in [Kate](https://kate-editor.org)?

Answer (score 6):

Try to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all text and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to cut it and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste it back. It will automatically format the indentation accordingly to your settings in Kate configuration.

Comment: Not anymore it doesn't

Comment: I can't get this to work either.   I have the setting checked: "Settings" -> "Configure Kate..." -> "Editor Component" -> "Editing" -> "Indentation" -> "Adjust indentation of code pasted from the clipboard".   It does not appear to convert tabs to spaces or vice-a-versa when pasting.

Comment: Works perfectly, converts all tabs, even those which don't have maximum length, to the correct amount of spaces. I do *not* have the box checked that @StephenOstermiller mentioned. Kate version 3.13.3

Comment: I currently have Kate v 17.04.3.   It looks like the 3.x versions are several years old.  This functionality must be broken in the newer versions.

Comment: Works on kate v23.

Answer (score 6):

Select the text you want to modify, then 'Tools > Clean Indentation'.

Comment: That's sort of an iffy solution.  Cleaning the indentation ensures that all your selected text follows the indentation mode you choose.  Depending on what mode you chose and why the indentation varies (like what you manually stuck at the beginning of the different lines), the results may be mixed.  It may try to at least make all of the indents uniform (not always successful), which may be based on a rule like the least indented line.

Comment: This seems to work for me, even in cases of mixed indentation.   If I have my preference set to "tabs" with four space width, it will replace all of the following with two tabs:   eight spaces), four spaces and a tab, a tab and four spaces, and even really mixed cases like six spaces and a tab (which would render as two tab widths).

Comment: Doesn't work for me in case of tabs in between letters, they are not converted to spaces. This is important e.g. for tabs in comments of programming languages.

Comment: Worked for me in Version 19.08.3.

Answer (score 2):

If you do Tools -> Switch to Command Line (or you hit F7), you can highlight the text in question and type the command "cleanindentation" in the command box.

Answer (score 1):

Select the text you want to modify and run it through 'Tools > Filter Text'. Use command '`expand -t4`' (or whatever indentation you want).

Comment: Also `unexpand -t4` to convert those spaces back to tabs instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the replacement dialog window. Now use mouse and mark one tabulator, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and paste it under "Find" section. Under section "Replace" just input four spaces and click "Replace all".

Comment: you can enter tabulator as "\t" and switch option "escape sequences" ON, no need to do sorcery with ctrl+C/V ...
But this will replace tabulator with fixed amount of spaces provided in the replace dialog, so it will break any indentation previously provided by the tab characters.

Answer (score 0):

In version 15.12.3, Try to do Ctrl + A to select all text and then select Tools -> Align.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> -> <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> -> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>

Assumes you've changed your `Settings -> Editing Options` to `Indent using Spaces`.